# How do i replace or remove on change selected text?

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, drop-down-menu

My select option has 'bla' text. when selected should be remove or replace the 'bla'.

```
<select class="myclass">
    <option value="1">Item 1</option>
    <option value="2">Item 1.1</option>
    <option value="3">someitem is bla</option>
    <option value="4">Item 1.2</option>
    <option value="4">Noya prem bla</option>
 <option value="2">Item 6.1</option>
 <option value="2">Item bla yakito</option>
</select>
```

When selected, should be like this.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qcf4g.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ywsNQ.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/TvrON.png

Answer (score 0):

```
$( "#myselect option:selected" ).text("Your text");
```

replace selected option text.

$("#myselect option:selected" ).text($("#myselect option:selected" 
   ).text().replace(/(bla)/g,""))

remove all "bla bla" in selected text

Comment: @Ahuahu Sorry! Were here to help, not to write code for you. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask