# How to use multiple function name together?

Tags: javascript, function

I have function but my script using different name by the function name. So, i want to use the function with or condition. Whats the rules?

```
function myfunction1 || myfunction2 (param){
  //some code
}
```

**Update**

```
var myfunction2 = myfunction1;
function myfunction1(param) {
    //some code
}
```

```
function myfunction1(param) {
    //some code
}
var myfunction2 = myfunction1;
```

whats the var implement rule? var should be before or after or both will work in jq/js?

Comment: You can create multiple variables that refer to the same function: (eg: `var myfunction2  = myfunction1;`)

Comment: Hi Ahuahu, welcome to [SO].  It's difficult to understand what you are asking. Are you trying to use two names for the same function?

Comment: You are trying to invent a new syntax for JavaScript. Could you elaborate a bit more on what your final goal is?

Comment: Yes, i have 1 function that i need to use the same function with different name. seems creating var method is working. means myfunction1 and myfunction2, both will act same function.

Comment: as i can see many expert of jq/js, could anyone check this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56819386/how-do-i-replace-or-remove-on-change-selected-text

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you add a variable that points to the original function. In that way, you can call myfunction1 or myfunction2 interchangeably. They will act the same.

```
function myfunction1(param) {
    //some code
}
var myfunction2 = myfunction1;
```

Comment: var should be after. Because you should first declare myfunction1. After you can use this.

Comment: Good to know :)